# Best way to add item to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to add items to my RecyclerView. I do this, when the user scrolls to a specific position. This works, also to get the data. I have a list to update. So the list has first 20 elements, then I load 20 and then the list has 40 elements. Load again and it has 60 elements and so on. But how can I add this now to the adapter? It should also stay at the current position.

Here I create the adapter:

```
MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(mainList);
```

This `mainList` is also the list to update. I don't know if it matter, I use StaggeredGridLayoutManager.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set the adapter to the recyclerView:

```
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When your list object was updated, notify it:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: That's very resource intensive,  though, when RecyclerView gives you the ability to only notify a subset of the view

Comment: or if you dispatch them one by one with: notifyItemInserted(list.size() - 1);

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to know the exact amount of data that is going to be loaded into the list, you can explicitly notify the new range of insertion.

```
notifyItemRangeInserted(int start, int itemCount)
```